# Search SQL request with two tables on PostgreSQL. SQLAlchemy. Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, search, request

Need help in request making on SQL or SQLAlchemy

First table named as **Rows**

| sid | unit_sid |
| --- | --- |
| ROW_UUID1 | UNIT_UUID1 |
| ROW_UUID2 | UNIT_UUID1 |
| ROW_UUID3 | UNIT_UUID |

Second table with name **Records**

| row_sid (==SID from ROWS) | item_sid | content (str) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ROW_UUID1 | ITEM_UUID1 | Decription 1 |
| ROW_UUID1 | ITEM_UUID2 | Decription 1 |
| ROW_UUID2 | ITEM_UUID1 | Description 3 |
| ROW_UUID2 | ITEM_UUID2 | Description 2 |
| ROW_UUID3 | ITEM_UUID1 | Description 5 |
| ROW_UUID3 | ITEM_UUID2 | Description 1 |

I need an example of a SQL query, where I can specify a search for several **content** values for different item_sid

For example I need all ROWS where

1. item_sid == ITEM_UUID1 and content == Description 1
2. item_sid == ITEM_UUID2 and content == Description 1

Request like bellow will not work for me, because I need search in two item_sid in same time for receiving unique ROWS

```
select  row_sid
from rows
    left join record on rows.sid = record.row_sid
    where (item_sid = '877aeeb4-c68e-4942-b259-288e7aa3c04b' and
          content  like '%TEXT%')
    and (item_sid = 'cc22f239-db6c-4041-92c6-8705cb621525' and
          content  like '%TEXT2%') GROUP BY row_sid
```

Comment: `where (item_sid = '877aeeb4-c68e-4942-b259-288e7aa3c04b' and content  like '%TEXT%')
 OR (template_item_sid = 'cc22f239-db6c-4041-92c6-8705cb621525' and content  like '%TEXT2%')`

Comment: No, I need search in two item_sid in same time. I need find unique rows where content for 1st item_sid == 'ONE' and content for 2nd item_sid == 'TWO'

Comment: That is why I used `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: In this case, I will get filtering by one item_sid, even if the second condition is not met. And I need to filter by two different item_sids in the same time

Answer (score 0):

Solved like

```
select  row_sid
from rows
    left join record on rows.sid = record.row_sid
    where (item_sid = '877aeeb4-c68e-4942-b259-288e7aa3c04b' and
          content  like '%TEXT%')
    or (item_sid = 'cc22f239-db6c-4041-92c6-8705cb621525' and
          content  like '%TEXT2%') GROUP BY row_sid having count(row_sid) = 2
```

But maybe there are more beautiful solution? I want to request different number of item_sids (2-5) in the same time